# Forwarding HTTPs requests to another webserver

Tags: networking, nat, port-forwarding

I have an **Ubuntu 12.04 Server** connected to **two subnets**.

**Eth0 is `20.20.20.1`**, it hosts an Apache Web Server on port 80. **Eth1 is dynamic IP address in `10.10.10.0` subnet**.

This server is not a gateway i.e. no workstations getways point to that server.

There is **another web server** located in the second subnet **at `10.10.10.1`**.

I would like users **from first subnet** be able to see this second server located in the second subnet. For example, if an user types **`http: //20.20.20.1`** (port 80) he sees the **1st web server** located in his own subnet, if an user types **`https: //20.20.20.1`** (port 443) he gets **forwarded** to the second subnet and sees **2nd web server** at **`10.10.10.1`**.

This is what I have tried:

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -d 10.10.10.1 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state \
    --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp  --dport 443 -j DNAT \
    --to-destination 10.10.10.1:443
```

However the requests from first subnet don't get forwarded to `10.10.10.1`, unfortunatelly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have two NICs on a `10.10.10.1` machine and the problem is in a source IP.

For example client `20.20.20.15` tries to access `https: //20.20.20.1`. You **DNAT** that traffic to `10.10.10.1:443`.

So now `10.10.10.1` receives a packet with a source IP `20.20.20.15`. There is no concrete rule for a `20.20.20.0/24` subnet so a reply is being sent via default gateway which is not connected to the `20.20.20.1` machine. Packet is going somewhere else and gets dropped eventually.

You need either to add `ip route 20.20.20.0/24 dev ...` on server `10.10.10.1`

Or to add a **SNAT** rule on `20.20.20.1`:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -d 10.10.10.1 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

But in this case in webserver logs you'll see MASQUERADEd IP address of your first (20.20.20.1 in this case) server in `REMOTE_ADDR` and maybe that's not good for you. So it's better to add a static route to the subnet as i mentioned earlier.

Comment: I have tried to add SNAT rule but it says "multiple -j flags are not allowed" and when I deleted "-J MASQUERADE" it said "SNAT --to-source must be specified"

Comment: Oh, there is a typo. Should be `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -d 10.10.10.1 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE`

Comment: I'm sorry, for some reason it doesn't get through. Is there any way I can debug this?

Comment: Look at tcpdump or other dump tools. To figure out where does the traffic flow.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any NAT or whatever. This is a basic routing task. Users on the 20.x subnet should use your ubuntu server as a gateway to the 10.x subnet. Automatic propagation of settings can be achieved by several ways.

Comment: There is another gateway in 20.x subnet that users use to go out to Internet and I can't change that setting.

Comment: is this gateway aware about how the 10.x subnet can be reached ?

Comment: It is a Windows server, I can probably make it aware if I would know how

Comment: you can add a route to the 10.x subnet via your ubuntu server by using the "route" command in an elevated shell along with a /p switch. if you will be doing that, remove the NAT rules from iptables, but leave the ip_forward flag.

Comment: I have tried different ways but can't figure this out. What would be the command?